# Can an expired checksum provide any warning to the user when they get to the site?

Tags: checksum

If a user clicks on a checksum link that has expired, I don't think they get any notification to that effect. This can mean, for example, that when renewing a membership, they might create a duplicate record if they use a different email etc.

Could civicrm provide a warning to the user?

I think this idea may be too specific for general use, but an extension that offers a 'self service' checksum option, ie 'please enter your email address and check your emails for a new link' might be useful.

Thoughts?

Comment: Agreed -- sounds good to me.

Comment: +1 - An extension to allows contacts to request a new link for expired links or self serve profile edits is a great idea - I suggested it as a solution for this question: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12110/how-to-generate-group-unsubscribe-link

Comment: Good idea. We use checksum links with Drupal webforms- if a user clicks an expired link they generally see an empty form with no obvious way to progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

[image: checksum expired notification]

Comment: hi Matt. that looks like a good outcome for the warning message. did you have any thoughts about the additional suggestion of 'click here to request a new checksum'? The latter issue may have privacy / security implications I can't wrap my head around, but perhaps no more than any 'request new password' solution does.

Comment: Might be good to have some other eyes on the wording, since for most users checksum might as well be spelled chkcmsu as far as the meaning they derive from it. May be something about 'having a contact record and expecting/wanting to see your data pre-filled on the form'?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an existing feature of CiviCRM and would need to be added by a programmer. You can open a ticket in JIRA (https://issues.civicrm.org) and see if anyone would be willing to pick-up this task. If no-one does, and you have a budget to pay for such improvements, you can ask for a quote on your ticket through the Paid Issue Queue (https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue).